# Kubernetes: Infinite Workload Using One Pod Per Task

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, infinite, task-queue

I’m trying to create something similar to Lambda functions on kubernetes.
I need to run each request on a separate pod. Once the container terminates successfully, the response is returned and the pod should be deleted, and a new one should be created.
I want to reduce the latency of start-up time, so I want to create the pods in advance and let them wait for requests. Scalability isn’t a concern at the moment, I’m fine with having only 5 pods listening in parallel at any given time.

I thought about using a deployment controller but it doesn’t allow “restartPolicy: never”, which means that after a pod terminates it will be restarted rather than recycled.
Then I found out about Jobs, and I was able to achieve the desired behavior by creating a job with finite completions, and a parallelism of 5. The problem is the finite completions part. If I change completions to “null” (infinite), the job will stop creating new pods after one pod terminates successfully.
So, essentially, I’m trying to use the logic of a finite Job controller but for an infinite number of completions.

- is there a better way to do it than using kubernetes jobs?
- is there a way to reset the completions of a job periodically to achieve the desired behavior with my current implementation?
- is there a way to create a job with infinite completions where terminated pods are constantly replaced?

I have seen other s/o posts with similar requirements where it was recommended to use a job with infinite completions and make the pods terminate with error on purpose to make the job replace them with new ones, but I don’t think it’s a good idea, especially monitoring wise.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a specific requirement to answer the first question based on considering similar to **Lambda**.

Can checkout the **[Kubeless](https://github.com/vmware-archive/kubeless)** (No more managed by **VMware**) & **[Knative](https://knative.dev/docs/)** (**CNCF** project) if it fits your requirements.

If the above does not solve your exact issue you can fall back to your suggested approach of using **Jobs**.

There is always the option to extend the behavior of existing K8s resources with **Custom Controller/CRD** in **K8s**.

Idea is to extend the behavior of with Controller like here doing **Daemon Job**, i wanted to schedule **JOB** pod it on all available **Nodes** and one complete POD should be **removed** unless be there in **restart/complete** state. [My Example Daemonset Job article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/daemon-job-crd-in-k8s-with-compositecontroller-f263b7f25cb9?sk=c24d5f903cb7744eca19d2584f09082d) - [GitHub Code](https://github.com/harsh4870/daemon-job-k8s-crd)

To write the Controller/Operator you have multiple option

- [Operator SDK](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/)
- [Meta Controller](https://metacontroller.github.io/metacontroller/api/compositecontroller.html) (Composite Controller)